# "Our group doesn't organize around X (bad thing), it organizes around Y (reasonable thing)"

Tags: phrases

I think it's called the "Mot and Bratley strategy," but obviously I'm wrong because it's unsearchable.

There's a name for an (often political) tactic, where someone has a core issue X that's totally reasonable, but does a bunch of other stuff that is less acceptable.  Whenever someone points out these issues, the person falls back to "I'm just focused on X," all of that other stuff is unrelated.

What's the name of this strategy?

Comment: Manipulation? That's what it sounds like to me.

Comment: It's in the family of manipulation, double-speak, dog-whistle, and many others.  But it has a very specific name.

Comment: Changing the goalposts.

Comment: Very similar, but still much more like "dog whistle."  They never pretend to be doing anything but the most reasonable form of their goal.  Meanwhile, the community is filled with far more radical rhetoric.  It's kind of like a mask.

Comment: Deflection? There needs to be a word for “fallacious appeal to topicality”

Comment: Core issue X may be enough for the party or person to win or keep winning. The argument may, in fact, be irrelevant for another topic, so the strategy may just be *Don't Care*. This may also come about because the politician's electorate has an opinion that differs from that of a greater majority (e.g. nation vs. state, or state vs. county, etc.).

Comment: There definitely is a term for this.  It's something like the "Name and Name fallacy" or "Name and Name strategy."  I've seen it used multiple times, but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: Sounds like you'll really know it when you see it, as you have set your sights on *a very specific name*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Motte and bailey](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Motte_and_bailey) which derives from a castle or fortification where you'd have an easy to defend central portion (the [motte](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motte)) and a harder to defend larger outer area (the [bailey](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bailey)). You move back and forth between positions depending on what's more convenient, much as the defenders of a castle might start in the less fortified open space but but retreat to the highly fortified mound. Reportedly coined by the philosopher Nicholas Shackel.